# Blazor Server App - Cookie can not be set

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm working on a project to demonstrate Authorization code flow. Therefore I don't want to use any library that handles the authentication for me, but I want to make the whole process myself.
I created an Blazor Server app (SignalR).
On index page there is a single "Connect" button, that starts the whole authentication process and it is as follows.

**Index.razor**

```
    //on button click
    protected async Task ConnectClick()
    {
        await ConnectService.Connect();
    }
```

**ConnectService.cs**

```
        public void CreateSession()
        {
            if(!_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("userId", out string userId))
            {
                _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("userId", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            }
        }

        public async Task Connect()
        {
            CreateSession();
            //Generate random string as "state" parameter for ACF
            var state = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            var authorizeArgs = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"client_id", ...},
                {"scope", ...},
                {"redirect_uri", ".../Auth/ConnectCallback"},
                {"response_type", "code"},
                {"state", state}
            };

            //Save state to cookie to verify in later step
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("state", state);

            var url = ... //prepare url, not important
            _navigationManager.NavigateTo(url);
        }

        public async Task ConnectCallback(string code, string state)
        {
            //Verify state
            if(!_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("state", out string stateValue) || stateValue != state)
            {
                throw new AuthenticationException();
            }

            ... //rest of authentication steps

            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("userId", out string userId);
            _memoryCache.Set(userId, access_token);
            _navigationManager.NavigateTo("/mypage");
        }
```

**ConnectCallback.razor**

```
    @page "/Auth/ConnectCallback"
    ...

    @code {

       protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
       {
          await AuthService.ConnectCallback(HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Query["code"][0], HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Query["state"][0]);
       }
```

I know that a library would handle this in much more cleaner way, but the goal is to show the flow in a small demo app.

This is the latest state. I don't know if it is better to save the access token directly in the browser, but for now I keep it in the memory paired with userId.

What happens in this case is whenever I try to append a cookie I will receive:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Headers are read-only, response has already started.
```

Now, I understand I'm doing something wrong. Does anyone know what would be the proper way to this, or what am I doing wrong here? I don't seem to find any solution to this anywhere.

Comment: The only solution is to redirect the page and set the cookie. I did exactly what you are doing and it's available here https://github.com/iso8859/AspNetCoreAuthMultiLang

Comment: I suggest you use JS Interop to call a javascript function to set your cookie.

Comment: Be careful about using `HttpContextAccessor`, I am sure in your ways that you will get problem in production stage!

Comment: @user13256346 , and what would be the proper way to use it then?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `CookieController` that you will use for cookie management and redirect to it.
`IsEssential` indicates that the cookie is necessary for the website to function correctly.

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CookieController : ControllerBase
{
  [HttpGet("SetStateCookie")]
  public async Task<ActionResult> SetStateCookie()
  {
    CookieOptions opt = new CookieOptions
    {
      IsEssential = true
    };
    Response.Cookies.Append("state", $"{Guid.NewGuid()}", opt);
    return Redirect("/");
  }
}
```